# Can someone tell me how this is a quadratic equation?

Tags: quadratics, fractions

I'm not sure how to complete this- Could someone help describe to me how exactly this is a quadratic equation? Or how can I manipulate the variables to make it one? It has been a while since I've worked with quadratics, also, I've never seen one like this before. Thanks for looking.

> $$\frac{1}{200-s} + \frac{1}{s} = \frac{1}{32}$$

Comment: Multiply everything by the common denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{200-s} + \frac{1}{s} &= \frac{1}{32} \\
\frac{200}{200s-s^2}&= \frac{1}{32} \\
\frac{200s-s^2}{200}&= 32 \\
200s-s^2 &= 6400 \\
-s^2+200s-6400&=0
\end{align*}
Do you see now?

Comment: Kind of.... What exactly did you do to get from the first step to the second step?

Comment: @pstumps
Get common denominator.
$$\frac{1}{200-s}+\frac1s = \frac{1}{200-s}\cdot \frac{s}{s} + \frac{1}{s}\cdot\frac{200-s}{200-s} =  \frac{s}{(200-s)s} + \frac{200-s}{(200-s)s} = \frac{s+200-s}{(200-s)s} = \frac{200}{200s-s^2}. $$

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks so much, I apprecaite it!